# Show/Hide fields if there is not in list

Tags: python, list, odoo, odoo-12

My concept is that I have 5 different access level on Odoo.

I want to check if login user is in list (list is created by an automated action), if yes show the fields else hide them.

My code:

```
list_of_users= []
if record.user_id.partner_id.id: #level 1 user add on list
  list_of_users.append(record.user_id.partner_id.id)

if record.user_id.sale_team_id.user_id.partner_id.id: #level 2 user add on list
  list_of_users.append(record.user_id.sale_team_id.user_id.partner_id.id)

if record.user_id.sale_team_id.regional_manager_id.partner_id.id: #level 3 user add on list
  list_of_users.append(record.user_id.sale_team_id.regional_manager_id.partner_id.id)

user_ids = record.env['res.users'].search([])
flag = record.env['res.users'].search([('groups_id','ilike','L4')])

for user_ids in flag: #level 4 and 5 users add on list
  user_record = record.env['res.users'].browse(user_ids)
  list_of_users.append(user_ids.partner_id.id)

record.update({'x_partner_follower_custom': [(6, 0, list_of_users)]})
```

On view i use `attrs="{'invisible': [('x_partner_follower_custom', '=', False)]}"` inside on fields i want to show/hide

`x_partner_follower_custom`: many2many res.partner field

Output Sample:
[image]

As you can see im return users back to view, but it seems the `attrs` is not properly set. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You can create a compute  Boolean field that will be True when the user belong to list of False if not. and use that field in the attrs. Because I don't think you have access to the current user in attrs evaluation but i'm not sure about this yet.

Comment: Hello, can you provide me some example because im new to odoo programming?

Comment: I made an extra boolean field on `res.partner` model what code should apply on compute field? [Image](https://ibb.co/zFBfxQk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the field should not be `stored` and it must be computed every time because it `depends` on the value of the current logged `user`, remove `store`:

```
   @api.depends('x_partner_follower_custom')
   def user_exist(self):
        for rec in self:
             if rec.x_partner_follower_custom and self.env.user.partner_id.id in rec.x_partner_follower_custom.ids:
                 rec.your_boolean_field_name = True
             else:
                 rec.your_boolean_field_name = False
```

So the field depends on `x_partner_follower_custom` and the current logged user it should not be `stored`.

**EDITS**

Everything is explained in the Form view and how to make the code works like it was created in the code:

[image: How to create a compute field using UI]

I manage it to find solution, a couple days ago: @Fotic

```
for record in self:
  if record['x_partner_follower_custom'] and self.env.user.partner_id.id in record['x_partner_follower_custom'].ids:
    record['x_partner_is_follower_custom'] = True
  else:
    record['x_partner_is_follower_custom'] = False
```

Comment: First of all thanks very much for the help,  if I use the above settings Im getting an empty list inside the contact (see images) [x_partner_is_follower_custom](https://ibb.co/4Y2xy0p), [x_partner_follower_custom](https://ibb.co/5xHwRw0),  [result](https://ibb.co/Xt9db4q). Also i test with `stored` ON but not seems to working, on view i use `attrs="{'invisible': [('x_partner_is_follower_custom', '=', False)]}"`. Any solution?

Comment: Sorry for using 'first of all', and the code I wrote is not for custom UI fields ut's for server side code, python code. To do the same in UI copy the body of the method in the Code field. And copy the dependencie in the dependencies field. Check this to understand what i'm saying and kepp store=False as I told you that field should be computed every time : https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/how-can-i-add-custom-fields-that-calculate-a-combination-of-other-fields-like-sales-margin-as-a-percentage-without-a-module-108580

Comment: Like this to assume? [many2many field](https://ibb.co/ZJQkFXQ) `x_partner_follower_custom` (list of users is created when record is created or updated), [boolean field](https://ibb.co/W26KFZQ) `x_partner_is_follower_custom` but im taking Error: `ValueError: forbidden opcode(s) in 'for rec in self:\r\n if rec.x_partner_follower_custom and self.env.user.partner_id.id ...`

Comment: The idea of the code is like I wrote it, but I think you cannot write code like this in UI. If I have time I will try to help you with this.

Comment: Im trying this way, because customer is not giving me access to ftp server. So if you have time to help me i whould be glad. Thanks

Comment: @Fotic sorry for taking so long, Check my edits I hope this helps you

Comment: Believe me I knew that you will manage to do that by yourself because you understood the idea